# Is there a "direct assignment" for Kotlin's null aware operator "?:"?

Tags: javascript, typescript, kotlin, null

So, in Dart and also TypeScript/JS we have the equivalent null-aware operator `??` to Kotlin's `?:`.

With this in mind, if we find ourselves in this situation: `a = a ?? b` we can easily use this shorter syntax: `a ??= b`. This comes in handy when we are accessing a nested property. It's kind of ugly to do something like this:

```kotlin
someObj.someProp.foo.bar = someObj.someProp.foo.bar ?: someOtherBar
```

when you could just do something like:

```kotlin
someObj.someProp.foo.bar ?:= someOtherBar
```

It really surprises me that I haven't found any Kotlin variant to the `??=` TS/JS and Darts' syntax. Has anyone ever encountered this?

Comment: If you find yourself doing that you're mis-using the typesystem. If there's a default for  `bar` that should be set immediately and its type shoudln't be nullable. In general if you're using `!!` a lot it means there's a way to restructure your code so that you don't need them as often

Comment: @al3c Because of business logic, `foo` can be null so we need to have it as nullable. Imagine that we are doing this inside a method that only gets executed if `foo` is not null, so we have already checked that before. The `!!` are just so that Kotlin does not complain. Maybe I should remove them from the question? They're not really a part of it.

Comment: @AnimeshSahu they don't look very clean. I made an extension, I'll post it as an answer but won't mark it as such in case other person has another answer

Answer (score 0):

I didn't found any native way of doing it, so I made an extension:

```kotlin
infix fun <T> KMutableProperty0<T?>.`?=`(other: T) = set(get() ?: other)
```

**Disadvantages**: it only works with a property of an object, not with local variable. Also, you have to use two dots "::" before the property that you use it with, because it's a way similar to use reference in Kotlin.

But overall, it looks really clean:

```kotlin
someObj.someProp.foo::bar `?=` someOtherBar
```

Comment: Using reflection makes this process upto 10x slower than normal `if` check: https://pl.kotl.in/totJZZtB- Just for clean looking code doing a runtime-overhead isn't the best way to deal with these situations.

Comment: @AnimeshSahu Hm I agree. I ran your code and it's interesting, because the timings vary a lot from time to time (from 5x to 29x). Do you know what causes this?

Comment: You can add more 9s in the loop to get more percise reading, in my IDE on my Ryzen 5 laptop, if you run it ~99,999 times it is consistent 15-17x slower. I put less iterations for not to make a heavy overhead on Playground.